# Ngrok - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: ngrok

I am installing Ngrok, but I am stuck at "Expose a local web server to the internet" I am using "ngrok http 80" this command and opening localhost page too. but sowing "502 Bad Gateway" Error

Comment: I have the same problem now. At the start it worked but now I don't know what changed. Found a solution to this?

Comment: are you using a Proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by making sure IIS Express was running on my PC.  In visual studio I ran my web app, that started up IIS and then closed it down.  Then NGROK started working again.  HTH Benjamin

Answer (score -1):

Try executing ngrok.exe as an administrator , and use the port 80 .
`ngrok.exe http 80`